# Repetir una promesa hasta resolverse

Tags: javascript, promesas

Estoy haciendo un ciclo validado con while, pero dentro tengo una promesa, yo quiero que se repita si no fue resulta, pero si fue resuelta entonces deje de repetir. el problema es que antes de que resuelva esta ejecutando un ciclo infinito haciendo explotar el programa, muestro lo que tengo

```
const validateBin = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            while(!this.validated) {
                  this.findEmail() // metodo async
                    .then(mail => {
                        console.log('mail found: ', mail)
                        this.validated = true
                        resolve()
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        reject()
                    }
           }
}
```

Comment: Solo tengo una pregunta: ¿Por qué?

Comment: Iba a preguntar lo mismo.. ademas ojala el servidor alguna vez conteste...

Comment: es que estoy pasando un dato a esa clase y ese dato debe ser resulto si o si, entonces estuve pensando que la unica manera es haciendo un ciclo hasta que se valide el dato, el problema es que el metodo `this.findEmail()` es asincrono. se me paso colocar eso

Comment: Debe ser resuelto si o si no es algo que vaya con una pagina web. y si se le cayo la conexion? mejor que sea el usuario quien reintente...

Comment: estaba pensando es hacer 3 intentos como minimo, luego mostrar la advertencia, pero sin haberse resuelto la promesa, se continuan agregando las otras

Comment: Las demas promesas que vayas hacer deberían depender de el "then" de la promesa que quieres que este llena sí o si o almenos 3 intentos que me parece razonable

Comment: Algo que no logro entender (tal vez por falta de contexto), es ¿porqué envolver una Promesa dentro de otra Promesa?. Tu método `findEmail()` devuelve una Promesa, no le veo el sentido a envolver la misma dentro de otra Promesa, en todo caso tendría sentido que la envolvieras en una función tipo `async` para usar `await`. Pero crear una Promesa para envolver el resultado de otra Promesa es algo redundante.

Comment: Por otro lado, sin saber exactamente lo que hace tu método `findEmail`, si el mismo devuelve un valor `null` o `undefined` o tal vez un objeto vacío, serían éstos elementos válidos pasados como parámetro a `then` y si tu validación depende de que la Promesa (`findEmail()`) sea resuelta, pero no validas estos casos, tu validación no tiene sentido. Es que por donde lo mire tienes varios problemas de lógica. ¿Podrías agregar lo que hace tu método `findEmail()` o al menos lo que devuelve el mismo? Te invito a repasar [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera en que se puede hacer es usando la recursión, y haciendo la evaluación dentro del callback, no fuera:

```js
const falsosRequests = ['https://falsorequest.com',
  'https://falsorequest.com',
  'https://falsorequest.com',
  'https://falsorequest.com',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
]

const validateBin = (i) => {
  fetch(falsosRequests[i])
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log("Respuesta exitosa"))//<-- No volvemos a hacer el ajax
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("hubo un error y repetimos")
      validateBin(++i); //<-- Solo en este caso volvemos a hacer el ajax
    });
}

validateBin(0);
```

Obviamente cambié el código para que funcione aquí, la evaluación no puede estar fuera del callback, porque es asíncrona, y en este caso no es necesario hacer un `if` porque la evaluación ya se hace con el `.then` o `.catch`. En tu código debería ser algo así:

```
const validateBin = () => {

  this.findEmail() // metodo async
    .then(mail => {
      console.log('mail found: ', mail)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      validateBin();
    });

}
```

No veo la necesidad de crear otra promesa.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta.